# How to edit remote response text on different git actions?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

For example, when pushing to BitBucket you get a text response from remote:

```
remote: 
remote: View pull request for test => master:
remote:   https://bitbucket/projects/DUMMY/repos/test/pull-requests/1
remote:
```

You also get a similar response when using gerrit - a link to code review.

Can this response be edited in BitBucket? Is it possible to make custom server responses for e.g. `fetch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern versions of the Git protocol provide a so-called sideband channel where various messages can be included.  It is possible for any Git server to send pretty much any message that it likes in this text, and as a result, if you write your own server implementation, it's possible to make it say whatever you want.

Having said that, I very much doubt that Bitbucket allows customization; GitHub doesn't, and I have no reason to think that they'll differ here.